# Spark how to union two arrays column without removing duplicates

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

There is function array_union, that union two arrays without duplicates. How can I union two arrays without removing duplicates?

```
+---------+---------+
|field    |field1   |
+---------+---------+
|[1, 2, 2]|[1, 2, 2]|
+---------+---------+
```

```
.withColumn("union", array_union(col("field"), col("field1")))
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------+------------------+
|field    |field1   |union             |
+---------+---------+------------------+
|[1, 2, 2]|[1, 2, 2]|[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]|
+---------+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `concat` instead,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat}

df1.withColumn("NewArr", concat("Array1","Array2")).show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]